# I have no photos in my album but it still says that it takes 508 MB of space on my iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, storage, album

So I have no photos in my phone, but it still says that it takes 508 MB when I look at my usage in settings. There is literally no photos at all, even the recently deleted has been deleted, and I don't have photo stream so I don't know what's going on. My iPhone is only 8 GB, so I'm trying to manage my storage the more I can.

Comment: "What" is saying it takes 508MB?  Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: @Allan the OP states "when looking at my usage in settings", I assume they mean Settings > General > Usage > (Storage) Manage Storage > Photos & Camera

Comment: Have you turned your phone off and on again? I think I've read some people succeeded in refreshing the available space indicator with that "sophisticated" method

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz - I just like to be clear.  I answered questions similar to this and assumed it was the system settings.  When we finally got down to it, it was an App that was not working properly.

Comment: @Allan fair enough